# How to get full 12-bit resolution of ds18b20 from w1_therm

Tags: ds18b20

The ds18b20 reports temperature in sixteenths of a degree; however, the w1_therm driver reports temperature in millidegrees, as a truncated integer. It takes half-millidegrees to accurately represent every sixteenth of a deg, so how do you get full resolution from the sensor?

For example, here is an emulated ds18b20 with temperature set to 23.0625 degC:

```
pi@xenon:~$ cat /sys/bus/w1/devices/28-00da18b20000/w1_slave
71 01 4b 46 7f ff 00 10 4e : crc=4e YES
71 01 4b 46 7f ff 00 10 4e t=23062
```

The driver reports 23.062 deg, so it's off by 0.005 deg. Of course, that's pretty small, but if you're looking for small temperature fluctuations you'll miss it.

Answer (score 1):

The first two bytes returned by the driver (`71 01`) are the actual reading from the sensor. They're in LSB order, so the reading is `0x171`, which is 369 sixteenths of a degree, or 23.0625 deg C.

Another way to look at it is to enumerate the decimal values of all 16 sixteenths of a degree (see below). We then observe that any millidegree reading that ends in a 2 or a 7, should really have a 5 after it. The rest are zero.

```
const char *frac[ ] =
{
  "0000", "0625", "1250", "1875",
  "2500", "3125", "3750", "4375",
  "5000", "5625", "6250", "6875",
  "7500", "8125", "8750", "9375"
};
```